# how to maintain session step by step in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular 4.
Please explain How to implement session functionality in angular 4.
Step by step process and where to write code for that.
i am trying to implement below code but need direction to implement

```
saveInLocal(key, val): void {
    console.log('recieved= key:' + key + 'value:' + val);
    this.storage.set(key, val);
    this.data[key]= this.storage.get(key);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you want to set session info you can just do

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('myKey', myValue);
```

to get it:

```
const sessionValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem('myKey');
```